# Loss function design for category-interrelated problem

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function

I wanna train a model to classify categories A, B, C and D, then I encode 4 classes into 4D vector. [1, 0, 0, 0] represents the sample is classified as A. Then we can feed train samples, forward propagation, compute loss and back propagation.

A common loss function is softmax_crossentropy, but when computing loss, it thinks the loss(y_pred=[1, 0, 0, 0], y_true=[0, 0, 0, 1]) has the same meaning with the loss(y_pred=[0, 0, 1, 0], y_true=[0, 0, 0, 1]). However these categories have specific relationship, A and B are closer than C or D, C and D are closer than A or B, so the the loss(y_pred=[0, 0, 1, 0], y_true=[0, 0, 0, 1]) should be smaller than the loss(y_pred=[1, 0, 0, 0], y_true=[0, 0, 0, 1]), so the model can be trained quickly forward to the truth function.

So how we design a reasonable loss function?

Comment: Just a suggestion by try classifying  in two steps, first classify whether AB or CD and then differentiate between them.

Comment: Try to look at this paper for inspiration: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.124.9242

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; beter suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).